# How to calculate the released energy in a fusion reaction knowing the mass of the reactants?

Tags: energy, mass-energy, fusion

this the reaction formula:$H^2_1 + H^3_1 ->He^4_2 + n^1_0$ (idk how to put the numbers in the left)

and I have the released energy of one reaction $E_r=2,8.10^{-12}J$, How to calculate the released energy if the mass of $H_1^2$ is $1g$ and the mass of $H^3_1$ is $2g$?

$N_A=6,02 . 10^{23}$

so I have to calculate the number of nuclei, but is it because it's fusion the number of nuclei is the half of the sum of the number of nuclei of both reactants? what about fission too?

thanks

and I'm sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tritium nucleus has approximately 3/2 times the weight of a deuterium nucleus.  So, if you have 1 gram of deuterium and 2 grams of tritium, you don't have enough deuterium for all of the tritium to fuse.  You would need 1.33 grams of deuterium.  So the energy released from 1 gram of deuterium and 2 grams of tritium would be very nearly the same as that from 1 gram of deuterium and 1.5 grams of tritium.

Comment: thanks a lot, I also asked in reddit and the combination of this answer and the other one made me understand